# Synchronization of date and time parameter on all smart-watches (Samsung Galaxy Watch Active) simultaneously, which are registered in Knox Configure

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

Let me tell you what I have done:

1) I sent a request for using a Knox Configure and after some time I obtained an access to this system;

[ https://sun9-27.userapi.com/c850620/v850620149/1e7122/LA1fvTAqaI4.jpg ]

2) Then I activated two trial licenses. One of them for SETUP EDITION profile, and another one for DYNAMIC EDITION. Trying to understand for what of kind of purposes these editions have been created, I came to conclusion that I need to use the latter;

[ https://sun9-18.userapi.com/c850620/v850620149/1e713c/EyqPDwrEPRQ.jpg ]

3) After that my Tizen-application, which is compatible with Samsung Galaxy Watches, was downloaded to the Knox Configure Dashboard system, I had to wait some time because this application need to be processed in system. It was probably because of security issues, I think;

[ https://sun9-43.userapi.com/c850620/v850620149/1e7145/h0CIAFfMCQo.jpg ]

4) While reading Knox Configure Admin Guide [ https://docs.samsungknox.com/KC-Getting-Started/Content/get-started.htm ] in the chapter "Step 1: Set up your Knox Configure account", I noticed the following information: "If you are planning to enroll devices for testing purposes, use the Knox Deployment App to add test devices into Knox Configure". In the end I have downloaded Knox Deployment App [ https://docs.samsungknox.com/KC-Getting-Started/Content/about-kda.htm#h2_4 ] to my Android-smartphone in order to deploy Tizen-application (mentioned earlier at step 3) to the Samsung Galaxy Watch Active;

5) As I mentioned before I sorted out that I was in necessity of using DYNAMIC EDITION profile (it has been told at step 2), so after the creation of this profile [ https://sun9-37.userapi.com/c850620/v850620897/1e94ba/wms534RUXdY.jpg ] and downloading of all devices to Knox Configure Console [ https://sun9-42.userapi.com/c850620/v850620897/1e94c4/XXS3wcSmnWI.jpg ], I asked myself if there is a possibility to push some notification to all registered devices simultaneously, namely to Samsung Galaxy Watches, for synchronizing their date and time parameter. At present, I failed on this question :(.

Could anyone tell me what I have to do in order to succeed on this issue?